# Android studio - can't see text in AppTheme

Tags: android-studio

I have just started android studio, and I can't seem to see the "Hello World" text in my build:

[image: pic]

When I switch to another theme I am able to see the text, what could be the problem?

Edit:
The color is not the same as the background.

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: does the theme's font text have white as the color?

Comment: Please share your layout and style xml files.

Comment: That pic is just displaying your layout. Layouts are not automatically refreshed all the time. There is a refresh button, if the problem isn't invisible text. You should be clear that you mean your text is not showing up in the running app, or just not showing up in the layout view.

Comment: edited. the problem is I can't see the text in the layout view.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information presented about the problem, you need the closing label of ConstraintLayout

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

they stay like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or you may need to restart the android studio cache
go to the menu file> restat caches / restart

I hope I've helped

Comment: I accidentally didn't copy </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> into the edit, but it is there.
I've restarted the cache, but it still doesn't show the text :(

Comment: try menu (build > clean project) wait for the job to finish and then (build > rebuild project)